# Replacing woocommerce title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I currently have a function that will output my own page title

```
if(!function_exists('my_woocommerce_shop_page_title' )){
    function my_woocommerce_shop_page_title( ) {
        if ( is_shop()){
            return '<h3 class="page-title">My page</h3>';
        } else{
            return ;
        }
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_page_title', 'my_woocommerce_shop_page_title');
```

But this will leave the default `<h1>` tag (empty) so I'll have:

```
<h1 class="page-title"></h1>
<h3 class="page-title">My page</h3>
```

I tried with removing the shop page title, but that removes it altogether. How to remove that empty `h1` tag?

Comment: CSS would do it, `h1.page-title { display: none; }`

Comment: I don't want the empty html, serves no purpose on page. If I can remove it out, I'd like to remove it ;)

Comment: `jQuery("h1.page-title").remove()` that should help :)

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably do that, or just remove the h3 tag, and let it be in h1 as the default. I don't think I can just remove the empty tag with hooks. Thanks for advice.

Comment: Exactly, unless you are prepared to modify the template and write your own filter, its probably not possible to remove the h1 tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are prepared to modify the template, you'll have to use an alternative solution to remove the empty h1 tag.

For eg: `jQuery("h1.page-title").remove()`